# Where are Visual Studio breakpoints saved?

Tags: visual-studio, breakpoints

I seem to be getting breakpoints from other programmers when checking out code...

Where is the list of breakpoints saved by Visual Studio? In the vbproj file? vbproj.user file? documents and settings? are they meant to be specific to the solution, the project, the user, the computer they are set on?

Thanks!

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6219969/303290 you can import/export breakpoints in case you have a workflow requiring that.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

They are saved in the <solutionname>.suo file.  SUO stands for Solution User Options, and should not be added to source control.

No .vbproj.user files should be in source control either!

Comment: In modern Visual Studio, they are in `.vs\project_name\v15\.suo`

Answer (score 15):

Starting from Visual Studio 2015 CTP solution and project related files are stored in the (hidden) *.vs* directory.

The path to the *suo* file for Visual Studio 2015 is *.vs\<SolutionName>\v14\.suo*.

Same pattern applies to VS2017, 19, 23... in case the subfolder will be v15, v16...

Comment: A little more info on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31879242/3063884