# Visual studio save development state

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins

Is there any Visual Studio addin/thing that will save the current set of open windows, bookmarks, and breakpoints, etc? Whenever I return to an issue, it takes a while to find reopen the appropriate classes, reset breakpoints, etc. Something that could load previously saved states for each issue would save a lot of time on issues that need to be readdressed several times in response to feedback.

Comment: As far as I know, it already does that, saving these details in the `.user` and `.suo` files. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72298/should-i-add-the-visual-studio-suo-and-user-files-to-source-control

Comment: Oops, sorry, I meant saving states for different items, then being able to load them when you need to return.

Answer (score 2):

As stated on [visualstudio.uservoice](https://web.archive.org/web/20150707061255/https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2394909-breakpoint-sets-or-groups-enable-disable-breakp) such a feature kinda exists. You can group breakpoints by labeling them in the breakpoints window and then perform actions on group level. Those actions include enable/disable and even import/export. As the msdn link on that uservoice spage is already down, you should check the [archived page](https://web.archive.org/web/20120930043531/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293674.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Oded hinted at the answer here.  Save off those files, particularly the .suo file (for your breakpoints and windows) at the moment you need that snapshot.  Restore it (Open/Close solution as required) when you want those windows and breakpoints set as they were at the time of the file save.

Comment: Although this works it has other implications and the user experience sucks - a typical workaround, but only a workaround. A "debug session state" incl. all breakpoints nice integrated in the UI shure makes sense. Sounds like a job for uservoice...