# How to write loggings to the Visual Studio output window?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'd like to extend my application with a kind of logging, where one can choose to log to a file and/or to log to the "Visual Studio" "output" window.

For the latter, it seems that the function `OutputDebugString()` is doing the trick, but only for "Debug" builds, and I'd wish to have this also for "Release" builds, so I came up with the idea of using tracepoints (at least, I think that tracepoints are also writing to the "output" window for "release" builds), but here I have a rather frustrating problem:
Tracepoints are a special kind of breakpoints and seem to be written to *.suo files, being present in `<project directory>\.vs\<project name>\v15` directory (see [Where are Visual Studio breakpoints saved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200114/where-are-visual-studio-breakpoints-saved)., thank you, Max).
My idea was to write a postbuild event, adding a tracepoint to every line in the *.suo file where a `log()` operation was called.

This, however, is not possible, for the simple reason that the *.suo files are binary :-(

Does anybody know of another way to add tracepoints to an application at build-time or how to write (with a "Debug"/"Release" switch) to the "output" window of Visual Studio?

Thanks in advance

Comment: From my understanding `OutputDebugString` supposed to work when debugger is attached, not just in "Debug" builds.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::cout`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OutputDebugString() should work in Release builds - if there is anything to consume the output (such as WinDbg.) [Debugging Tools for Windows (WinDbg, KD, CDB, NTSD)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/) 
As to why it's not - probably want to look into that, as it's possible your application isn't building quite the way you expect otherwise.

As I understand it, Tracepoints only work in a debugger (Debug or Release) - but the way I believe this works is, the debugger will, on application load/startup, (or during a run) actually replace instructions with a BRK and when the application triggers the break, the debugger catches it, substitutesthe original instruction back in, before performing whatever task it should (whether that be pause, increment a counter, etc.) - but I think Tracepoints will only work with an attached debugger, as otherwise there's nothing to perform the replace, catch and substitute operations, and the code runs uninterrupted.

However, if I read your intentions correctly, you might actually want to use something like [Event Tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363668(v=vs.85).aspx)* instead. This should output what you want to see to a standard windows log file, will work in debug or release, inside or outside of a debugger. However it won't output to the VS output window. For that, OutputDebugString() should the be correct operation.

*Disclaimer - not used them myself, as we use VS output and WinDbg for now - but it looks like a better way for deployed applications, going forwards.