# Is there anyway to Undo removed breakpoints in c#?

Tags: c#, debugging, breakpoints

I added some breakpoints in my c# code using Visual Studio and by pressing **ctrl+shift+F9**, I removed all of them from Solution.

I was wondering if is there any way to undo current breakpoints as I need them now to debug the code.

also, Is there any way to save these breakpoints for future debugging?

Comment: No Undo but: Yes you can [save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200114/where-are-visual-studio-breakpoints-saved) them. Also [see here](https://dailydotnettips.com/import-and-export-breakpoints-in-visual-studio/)

Comment: Don't forget, often a really easy way to get to relevant code that needs debugging is to break on all exceptions not just uncaught ones.  Show the Debug>>Exceptions tool panel and put a tick next to CLR Exceptions - now as soon as any exception is thrown you'll break. You can turn it off on a per exception basis as they throw, if you're finding that there are a lot of useless ones like ThreadAbort when your code redirects etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't. You'll have to manually put them back on the lines that you had them.

In the future, I recommend that you use the "Disable All Breakpoints" option instead of deleting them. This way you can switch them on and off as necessary.

Comment: Yeah that will be good approach. Thanks for the post.